# notifydatasetchanged on recyclerview item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `RecyclerView` with an `ImageButton` in it. I want to update my `RecyclerView` with new Items on `onClick()` event of ImageButton. It works fine with my database but it doesn't refresh my RecyclerView.

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Quote current =  data.get(position);
    holder.quote.setText(current.getQuote());
    holder.name.setText(current.getName());
    holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(current.getId()));

    if (current.getIsLiked()==1){
        holder.quote.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#c0392b"));
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e74c3c"));
        holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ecf0f1"));
    }else if (current.getIsLiked()==0){
        holder.quote.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fefefefe"));
        holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));
        holder.relativeLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(11);
    }

    holder.imgIsLiked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        DataBaseHelper db=new DataBaseHelper(context);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (current.getIsLiked()==0){
                db.updateDatabase(current.getId(), 1);
                swap();
            }
            else if (current.getIsLiked()==1){
                db.updateDatabase(current.getId(), 0);
                swap();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void swap(){
    List<Quote> data2 = new ArrayList<Quote>(data);
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(data2);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and here is my fragmnt :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedState){
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.quotes_fragment,container,false);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.quotes_fragment_recyclerView);
    DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper=new DataBaseHelper(getContext());
    adapter = new QuoteAdapter(getContext(), dataBaseHelper.getAllData());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

Updated:
Thanks to Selvin the solution is :

```
        holder.imgIsLiked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(context);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (current.getIsLiked() == 0) {
                current.setIsLiked(1);
                db.updateDatabase(current.getId(), 1);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (current.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                db.updateDatabase(current.getId(), 0);
                current.setIsLiked(0);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: but swap does nothing

Comment: @Pavan I tried that before and no it didn't work

Comment: payam I will not help you but few hint: ... updating the database(prolly this `db.updateDatabase()` does) will not automatically update the underlaing Adapter's data ... you need to realod it almost in the same way as you did it initially ... (or at least use `current.setIsLiked()`  in click handler - then there is no need for swap ... simple notifyDataSetChanged should do the thing)

Comment: @payam here your dataset reference is changed so as Selvin suggested you have to call from adapter initialization process to setdapter to list. here i will suggest you to update your dataset on button click with properties you want and just fire notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Selvin thanks for your guldens  for proper comments

Comment: @Selvin Thanks alot. your hint did the trick.you can post it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this call this function on onClick function

```
public void foo(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
    }
```